# Dynamic allocating in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

I am having trouble with dynamic allocating.  My program needs to take in a text file, take in each word, and put them into an array while counting repeated words.  I think that I am malloc-ing the words into the array correctly, however I do not understand how to make an array with the struct I have created using dynamic allocating.  i.e. it needs to grow as the list does.  Thanks for any help you can give me.  The areas that I have commented out are also areas of trouble.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef unsigned int uint;

typedef struct wordType
{
    char * word;
    uint count;
};



/* store the string in another temp string which you can iterate through
and compare with the array of non-repeated words.  if there, increment*/


int main( void ) 
{
    typedef struct wordType * WORD_RECORD;
    WORD_RECORD arrayOfWords = malloc(10 * sizeof( WORD_RECORD) );

    FILE * inputFile;
    char temp[50];
    uint i;
    uint j;
    uint size;
        uint exists;
        inputFile = fopen( "input.txt", "r");



    if( inputFile == NULL )
    {
        printf( "Error: File could not be opened" );
        /*report failure*/
        return 1;
    }   
    i = 0;
    size = 0;
    while( fscanf( inputFile, "%s", temp) == 1 )
    {
        exists = 0;
        for( j = 0; j < size; j++ )
        {
            if( strcmp( arrayOfWords[j].word, temp ) == 0 )
            {
                arrayOfWords[j].count++;
                exists = 1;
            }
        }
        if( exists == 0 )
        {
            arrayOfWords[i].word = malloc(sizeof(char) 
                                    * (strlen(temp)+1));
            strcpy( arrayOfWords[i].word, temp );
            /*arrayOfWords[i].count++;*/
            size++;
        }
        i++;
    }

    for( i = 0; i < (size-1) ; i++ )
        printf("%s\n", arrayOfWords[i].word);


    fclose( inputFile );
    /*for( i = 0; i < size-1; i++ )
        free( arrayOfWords[0].word );*/
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any build errors? I have a very good feeling that you should be using `->` to dereference the `word` and `count` variables because you're storing struct pointers.

Comment: Incorrect on the `->` notation, WORD_RECORD may be a pointer but he's using malloc() to allocate storage for ten structs and the dot notation is appropriate. Nothing wrong with using a typedef, what do you mean "prevents encapsulation"? calloc() is a viable alternative method for allocating storage, but the only advantage in my opinion is that it initializes the allocated storage, which the questioner is forgetting to do in the question code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be using `malloc()` correctly to initialize your arrayOfWords array. you can grow the array using the `realloc()` function, but you'll have to keep track of how large it is any how many words you have, so you'll know when to call `realloc()`. In the case of `if ( exists == 0 )`, the variable `arrayOfWords[i].count` hasn't yet been initialized, so assuming it is zero is a bug, attempting to increment it is a bug, and anything other than setting it to an explicit value (in this case, `0`), is a bug.

You appear to be using `i` to count the total number of words you've read, not *unique* words you've read, so using `i` as your loop counter when you print the words out is wrong as well. The same holds for when you're freeing the `malloc()`'ed words: using `i` as the loop counter means you end up `free()`ing thing you didn't get from `malloc()`.

To dynamically grow the storage for your list of words, you'll need to keep track of how many `struct wordType` items you've allocated storage for, and when adding a new word, check if you've reached your limit, and `realloc()` if necessary.

When looping to print (and to free) the words, why are you doing "size - 1" ?